# Sending Java Packets to Python Server?

Tags: java, python, client, udp

I'm just starting to learn about sending UDP packets, and I'm running into a problem. I've written a Java client and server which easily communicate with each other, and I've done a Python client/server combo, but I'm not sure how to send a UDP packet from Java and receive it in Python. Here's what I have for the Java client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class testclient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

        System.out.println("Sending...");
        socket.send(packet);

        System.out.println("Receiving...");
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
        System.out.println(received);
        System.out.println("Done!");

        socket.close();
    }
}
```

And the Python server:

```
from sys import *
from socket import *

host = gethostname()
port = int(argv[1])
address = (host, port)

print "Binding..."
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(address)

print "Receiving..."
data, client = sock.recvfrom(256)

print "Sending to", client
sock.sendto("Hi", client)

print "Closing..."
sock.close()

print "Done!"
```

All I'm trying to do here is send a request from the Java client to the Python server, then have the Python server send "Hi" back to the Java client, and have the client print the string. What happens for me is the client sends the packet, and the server waits at the `sock.recvfrom(256)` and never receives the packet (or that's what it looks like anyway).

Any ideas? I'm guessing it's some difference between how Java and Python handle the packets but, I'm not sure.

EDIT: Just for clarification, the port number is passed in via command-line arguments for both of these applications.

Comment: What does `gethostname()` return (try it on the interactive interpreter). It's possible that you're binding on an external interface, not `localhost == 127.1`, as it seems you intend to do in the above snippets.

Comment: It returns the name of my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to start, I'm on Ubuntu 10.10.

I went into /etc/hosts and it looks like 127.0.0.1 was assigned to localhost.localdomain, while 127.0.1.1 was assigned to my machine's name. So, Python was using the localhost address, while Java was using my machine name address. I changed localhost to my machine name and everything works now.

Thanks everybody for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be within your code, they should be able to communicate: [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html)
is a good example of writing a client server pair in java.

Comment: Thanks, but I've followed that tutorial already. I wrote a client server pair by following that and it works fine. But, once I start using a Python server instead, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: maybe try specifying the port it is listening on would help, are you sure that your client and server are listening on the same port?

Comment: Also, it may be useful to have your code for a client and server each running in their own separate thread daemon (so they die when your program is finished).  Also it does not look like your server is running in a loop (ie. for(;;)) which could be a problem.  Does your server print anything out when you run it?

Comment: Yeah it gets up to printing out "Receiving..." I just want it to receive the packet, send a packet to the client, then exit. So in this case, no loop necessary. I'm sure they're listening on the same port, because I pass the port number in via command-line arguments.

Comment: try printing out the port and host name from each the client and the server just to make sure that they are trying to connect to the same thing.  It does not seem to make sense that the problem would be in the implementation of the protocol.

Comment: also, try using running netstat that could help as well

Comment: Hmmm, @John this is odd. For Python I am using gethostname() and in Java I'm using InetAddress.getLocalHost() so you would think those would return the same thing. But when I print everything out, Python is using the IP 127.0.0.1 and Java is trying to send to 127.0.1.1. I wonder why that is.

Comment: I figured it out. I'll post an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, I see where you create the packet, but I don't see you actually putting any data into the packet using [`setData`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#setData%28byte%5B%5D%29) before sending it.

Comment: Just tried setting the data, doesn't fix it. But, I figured I wouldn't have to set the data in the client packet anyway, because it's more of a request than actually sending information.